# Unable to establish audio communication between Handsfree and Android mobile

Tags: android, mobile, audio, bluetooth

My requirement is to develop a Application which will Receive call, disconnect call and Dial a number from handsfree to android mobile via bluetooth[Paired] using Handsfree Profile.

Note: I am trying to make one mobile phone as Handsfree and from other mobile I am trying to pair via bluetooth and if call comes to mobile phone I should be able to receive and speak from handsfree mobile phone. Is this possible???

After crawling n number of post I am able to send AT command from handsfree to Android mobile. So if I get call in Android mobile I am able to disconnect call and also I am able to make a call from handsfree device by running following code in handsfree.

```
m_oBluetoothSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
Log.i("Not Connected +:  ", "Socket Connected");

mmInStream = m_oBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
mmOutStream = m_oBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

// AT command to receive call
 mmOutStream.write("ATA\r".getBytes());
    dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
    av = dis.available();
    if (av != 0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[av];
        dis.read(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b) + "Recieved form modem");
}
```

To disconnect call I replaced `ATA\r` with `AT+CHUP` command.

The issue I am facing is after I receive the call I am not able to speak or hear nor do a audio communication with the mobile.

I followed this guide to achieve this, but I am unable to perform audio communication after I receive call from Handsfree.

http://www.mcpc-jp.org/news/pdf/CCAP_Guideline_Ver10a.pdf

In the above doc I followed 6.2.5.1. Answer an incoming call from the HF (No in-band ringing) section by using following code.

```
m_oBluetoothSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
Log.i("Not Connected +:  ", "Socket Connected");

mmInStream = m_oBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
mmOutStream = m_oBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

 mmOutStream.write("AT+CIND=?\r".getBytes());
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
    int av = dis.available();
    if (av != 0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[av];
        dis.read(b);
        System.out.println(new String(b) + "CIND=? Recieved form modem");
 }

mmOutStream.write("AT+CIND?\r".getBytes());
dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
av = dis.available();
if (av != 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[av];
    dis.read(b);
    System.out.println(new String(b)
            + "CIND Recieved form modem");
}

mmOutStream.write("AT+CMER\r".getBytes());
dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
av = dis.available();
if (av != 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[av];
    dis.read(b);
    System.out.println(new String(b) + "NREC Recieved form modem");
}

mmOutStream.write("AT+NREC=0\r".getBytes());
dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
av = dis.available();
if (av != 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[av];
    dis.read(b);
    System.out.println(new String(b) + "NREC Recieved form modem");
}

mmOutStream.write("AT+CHLD=?\r".getBytes());
dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
av = dis.available();
if (av != 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[av];
    dis.read(b);
    System.out.println(new String(b) + "CHLD  Recieved form modem");
}

mmOutStream.write("ATA=?\r".getBytes());
dis = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
av = dis.available();
if (av != 0) {
    byte[] b = new byte[av];
    dis.read(b);
    System.out.println(new String(b) + "CHLD  Recieved form modem");
}
```

Permission present in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I am able to get appropriate response from Android mobile, but after receiving call I am unable to speak and hear.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do you have any logs from when you run your use-case? In particular from the `AudioPolicyManager` and `AudioHardware` modules?

Comment: AudioPolicyManager and AudioHardware are required to capture...  I am not aware of it....  I dont think those are required.  As I mentioned above I am able to receive call, but if I speak from headset called person is not able to hear....  When I get a call to the phone I see a bluetooth headset icon, I enabled that too... But still I am not able to speak[I mean stream audio]...

Comment: What do you mean by _"are required to capture"_? Those logs are enabled by default on my Samsung phone. Using those logs you should be able to see the voice call routing decisions being made.

Comment: I missed the main part of the requirement. I am trying to make one mobile phone as Handsfree and from other mobile I am trying to pair via bluetooth and if call comes to mobile phone I should be able to receive and speak from handsfree mobile phone. Is this possible???

Comment: If the other mobile is able to act as a BT accessory implementing the Handsfree Profile, then it should work (whether it's possible to get a phone to do that, I don't know). Otherwise I doubt it. There's no way for an Android app to take some audio data and inject it into the uplink of a voice call.